# Replacing ListFragments with "fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace"

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I've just started properly working with Fragments. I'm building an app that uses a drawerlayout and am trying to tweak google PlanetFragment example app just to see how it works.

I think I'm there but I'm using a listfragment no just a fragment as the original app is using.

The code below both has the google code commented and mine below. The content_frame id it refers to is a framelyout it replaces. Should I use a linear layout there?

The error it gives is it says I'm using a listfragment where fragment manager desires a normal fragment. I couldn't find anything that says this method shouldn't work with listfragments...

```
//        // update the main content by replacing fragments
//        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
//        Bundle args = new Bundle();
//        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
//        fragment.setArguments(args);
//
//        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
//        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        ListFragment fragment = new MyCategoryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing fragments from the compatibility package(the `MyCategoryFragment` should extend `ListFragment` from `android.app.ListFragment`) with the ones from the SDK.